# EF code first. Настройка конфигурации отношений

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, fluent-interface

К примеру. Есть класс `Account` и таблица `Accounts`. По мимо других свойств есть у него свойство `Type` типа `AccountType`. Данное свойство указывает на принадлежность к типу аккаунта. Сами типы находятся в таблице `AccountTypes` в виде

```
id  Name
1   Базовый
2   Премиум
3   Ультра топ жир
```

Соответственно какой должна быть конфигурация, что бы связать эти две таблицы? 
Вариант `public virtual AccountType Type` вроде бы и делать что мне надо, но при добавлении новой сущности `Account`, каждый раз добавляются и новые записи в таблицу `AccountTypes`. Явное указание `AccountTypes.Id` не помогает

```
public class DocumentDb
{        
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ActKindDb AktKind { get; set; }
}

public class ActKindDb
{
    public int Code { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Datetime Create { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

Класс `ActKindDb` выступает в роли справочника. На фронте будет только возможность выбора записи по имени из какого `DropDown (Combobox)`. Фактически, в таблицу `Documents(DocumentDb)` нужно добавить FK на `ActKindDb.Code`

Comment: приведите Ваш код

Comment: Привел пример кода. ActKindDb выступает в той же роли, как, к примеру, список существующих государств. Т.е. эта таблица будет один раз заполнена и в идеале больше изменяться не будет. Т.е. на SQL надо что-то типа поля DocumentDb.ActKind_Id как FK ActKindDb.Code

Comment: так у Вас проблема быстрей всего в коде на клиенте, допустим если Вы выбрали запись в Combobox то в Account.AccountTypesId должно писать значение которое ссылается на AccountTypes.Id

Comment: Начало вопроса -таблица называется Accounts, к концу вопроса -- DocumentDb. Чему верить? Таблиц две и вы просто поменяли реальные названия в начале вопроса и забыли в конце? Таблиц три и вы половину связей не описали нам? Что?

Comment: Привязка полей - смотреть в сторону атрибутов EF6